# What is the best method for determination ASP.net website clients?

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, networking

I have a asp.net webapp, and runs in private network 
I want determine PCs clients for

1. allow or block the requests
2. knows who is connected
3. connects only by special PCs
4. and more

I used IP Addresses, but anyone can connect when change the IP Address by one that passed in webapp, I want users login by just some PCs . any suggestions ?

Comment: Are all of the systems part of the same Windows domain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LOGIN and PASSWORD going to a database of preferences...  The best way to control everything about users (IP control can be bypassed, it´s not a valid control).

**UPDATE**

New method to pass info in URL:

**To get hardware information:**

```
Dim query As New SelectQuery("Win32_bios")
Dim search As New ManagementObjectSearcher(query)
Dim info As ManagementObject
For Each info In search.Get()
     BIOS_Msg = info("version").ToString()
Next

Dim searchMainboard As New ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_ComputerSystem")
Dim infoMain As ManagementObject
For Each infoMain In searchMainboard.Get()
    Computer_Mainboard = infoMain("model").ToString()
Next
```

**To encode Strings:**
You may set a KEY and IV as byte array. The key may change according date and even some specific parameters according to the current time.

Add also:

```
Imports System.Security.Cryptography
Imports System.Text


Friend Function EncryptStringToBytes_Aes(ByVal plainText As String, ByVal Key() As Byte, ByVal IV() As Byte) As String
    ' Check arguments.

    Dim encrypted() As Byte

    ' Create an AesCryptoServiceProvider object
    ' with the specified key and IV.

    Using aesAlg As New AesCryptoServiceProvider()
        aesAlg.Key = Key
        aesAlg.IV = IV

        Dim encryptor As ICryptoTransform = aesAlg.CreateEncryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV)

        ' Create the streams used for encryption.
        Using msEncrypt As New MemoryStream()
            Using csEncrypt As New CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write)
                Using swEncrypt As New StreamWriter(csEncrypt)
                    'Write all data to the stream.
                    swEncrypt.Write(plainText)
                End Using
                encrypted = msEncrypt.ToArray()

            End Using
        End Using
    End Using

    ' Return the encrypted bytes from the memory stream.
    Return Convert.ToBase64(encrypted)

End Function 'EncryptStringToBytes_Aes
```

**To decrypt it:**

```
Friend Function DecryptStringFromBytes_Aes(ByVal cipherText As String, ByVal Key() As Byte, ByVal IV() As Byte) As String

    Dim plaintext As String = Nothing
    Dim SourceText as Byte() = Convert.FromBase64(CipherText)

    ' Create an AesCryptoServiceProvider object
    ' with the specified key and IV.
    Using aesAlg As New AesCryptoServiceProvider()
        aesAlg.Key = Key
        aesAlg.IV = IV

        ' Create a decrytor to perform the stream transform.
        Dim decryptor As ICryptoTransform = aesAlg.CreateDecryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV)

        ' Create the streams used for decryption.
        Using msDecrypt As New MemoryStream(SourceText)

            Using csDecrypt As New CryptoStream(msDecrypt, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read)
                Using srDecrypt As New StreamReader(csDecrypt)

                    ' Read the decrypted bytes from the decrypting stream
                    ' and place them in a string.
                    plaintext = srDecrypt.ReadToEnd()

                End Using
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using


    Return plaintext

End Function 'DecryptStringFromBytes_Aes
```

Using these functions, you can:
- Get specific hardware info;
- Encode any string and convert it to Base64
- Pass them in URL using normal convention.
- Receive them in your code-behind and translate them.

I guess that´s the best way to get reliable and specific information of each workstation instead IP-number.  You may also work with the Windows Serial Number.

Comment: thanks for responded,  yes I used accounts for users in my web app and that is not my problem , I want users login from some PCs not another one in network that what about I talked it ...

Comment: If you have total control over each workstation (I mean, you can phisicaly access them), you may create an application to call the browser passing specific parameters like BIOS messages and other data at the URL, in a HASH mode (perhaps SHA256). It´s safer than IP or "clean text". For instance: get BIOS message and disk volume, call SHA256 and call browser passing URL like: "192.168.200.100?v=868661761763837687361871268612831286386186386816" where V is a variable to be check in your behind-code.

Comment: Best than this (since user can copy the URL) you can pass parameters to hidden fields, calling them really as a parameter (Set/Get).

Comment: good idea and thanks ,, but is not copy URLs only way to access, can someone get the hash code from browser ! or if he is a programmer can get the info and encrypt algorithm and gone from any PC.. tell me if my think is wrong ,,, sorry but I put all probabilities for pass it because that more than 100 PC runs it and the app has money accounts in db ...

Comment: You may adopt AES instead HASH. Using PKCS passwords, the encryption result will be always different and you may encode ALSO the current date and hour - so, if you receive a VALID encode string BUT with old date/hour than teh current, it´s a false login. See the MS samples of AES encode and you will find all you need.

Comment: Important: the above method will function 100%, but you will have to translate the encoded data to Base64, ok?

Comment: That all your answers is Ok.  thanks David, is very good idea, and I want ask another question, if I used Windows Service app and sends hash code by Http-Listener ( small http server in PCs ) instead of browser, is this safe method ?

Comment: Hmmm... I don´t think it´s safer than AES since you can have another problems related to this (Service and Listener).  Think about 2 variables: L = encoded LOGIN, B = BIOS/Disk Info;  and T = current date and time. Your receiving code must allow some minutes of discrepancy (something like 5 minutes). Since you encode both and translate to Base64, you can pass them in URL normally, with no risk.

Comment: See this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aes(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: And this: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8b0bbbdc-c39c-414e-bec2-c57c53f83526/simple-aes-encryption?forum=winappswithcsharp

Comment: Thanks a lot David for help . And how I can connect you when I need a some help ?

Comment: You´re welcome... If so, I can try to put another answer here. Is it enough to you?  I don´t know how to privately send my mail to you..

Comment: Done here... See above...  :)  And if you see as OK, please, vote...  :)